# Experience gain for mastering items with gold in Infinity Blade 2

Tags: infinity-blade-2

I have played through Infinity Blade 2 a few times and I sometimes master items using gold.

I was wondering whether or not this actually gives me the experience for my character to level up or only give one stat point?

Answer (score 2):

It gives both. The exchange rate is three gold per point of experience, rounded up to the nearest thousand.